# Insert Syntax in SQL: Without INTO and VALUE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I'm understanding a stored procedure, here's part of the code:

```
INSERT [dbo].[PartitionMaintenanceTables] (
    nvc_TableSchema,
    nvc_TableName, 
    i_CompressInterval,
    vc_CompressType,
    i_RetainInterval,
    dt_CreatedDatetime,
    dt_ChangedDatetime,
    dt_DeletedDatetime,
    ti_NeedsRepl,
    nvc_ChangedDatabaseName
)
```

As you can see, it's not inserting any value into this table. What does it mean? Is it inserting a bunches of default / null values to them?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thx!

Comment: You're missing part of the query. What's comes after this?

Comment: That's only half a statement.  Where's the rest???

Comment: Your statement has to be followed by something that provides values for the columns in the list. This can be either a VALUES clause, a SELECT statement or an EXEC statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax like:

```
INSERT tab(col); -- is invalid
```

`INTO` is optional. As for missing `VALUES` clause you probably have `SELECT` after insert:

```
INSERT tab(col) SELECT ...;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1dff8c3765bb2a8871d0da9e897004ca)**

Answer (score 1):

That code by itself will generate a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.